# I2s full-duplex communication with esp32 and arduino

Tags: audio, arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32, i2s

I'm trying to do a kind of audio interface using the INMP441 microphone as input, and the MCU-5102 as output device. The idea is to do it in Real Time, with the perform of simple convolutions to make effects on output signal. But I can't do at even full-duplex communication between components using i2s, I done it ones but with very bad quality, and since then I couldn't replicated it, and also EN pin generates some kind of error that doesn't let me go forward. This happened on projects that only involve the output of MCU-5102, as the radio Wi-Fi, it sometimes make the project fail. But that's another subject(or maybe not :/). I just want to know what I'm doing wrong in theory, trying to perform full-duplex communication, and in case of convolution, should I use another buffer??. I'm using ESP-32 and Arduino IDE , but I didn't find a functional clue to make this work. this is my code.

```c
#include <driver/i2s.h>

#define SIGNAL_LENGTH 100
#define KERNEL_LENGTH 10

//INMP441
#define I2S_WS 19
#define I2S_SD 21
#define I2S_SCK 18
// Uso del procesador 0 I2S
#define I2S_INPUT_PORT I2S_NUM_0

//WCMCU
#define I2S_BCK 27
#define I2S_LCK 26
#define I2S_DIN 25
#define I2S_OUT_NC -1
#define I2S_OUTPUT_PORT I2S_NUM_1

//Constantes compartidas de definición de protocolo I2S
#define I2S_SAMPLE_RATE 44100
#define I2S_BUFFER_COUNT 8
#define BITS_PER_SAMPLE 16
#define I2S_BUFFER_LEN 128

int samplesPerBuffer =  (I2S_BUFFER_LEN / BITS_PER_SAMPLE);

int16_t inputSoundBuffer[I2S_BUFFER_LEN];
int16_t outputSoundBuffer[I2S_BUFFER_LEN];

void i2s_install() {
  // Configuración del I2S
  const i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
    .mode = i2s_mode_t(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_RX | I2S_MODE_TX ),
    .sample_rate = I2S_SAMPLE_RATE,
    .bits_per_sample = i2s_bits_per_sample_t(16),
    .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ONLY_LEFT,
    // .communication_format = i2s_comm_format_t(I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S | I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S_MSB),
  //.communication_format = i2s_comm_format_t(I2S_COMM_FORMAT_PCM),
    .communication_format = i2s_comm_format_t(I2S_COMM_FORMAT_STAND_I2S),
    .intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1,
    .dma_buf_count = I2S_BUFFER_COUNT,
    .dma_buf_len = I2S_BUFFER_LEN,
    .use_apll = false,
    .tx_desc_auto_clear = true,
    .fixed_mclk = 0
  };

  const i2s_pin_config_t pin_config_o = {
    .bck_io_num = I2S_BCK,
    .ws_io_num = I2S_LCK,
    .data_out_num = I2S_DIN,
    .data_in_num = -1
  };


   const i2s_pin_config_t pin_config_i = {
    .bck_io_num = I2S_SCK,
    .ws_io_num = I2S_WS,
    .data_out_num = -1,
    .data_in_num = I2S_SD
  };

  i2s_driver_install(I2S_INPUT_PORT, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
  i2s_set_pin(I2S_INPUT_PORT, &pin_config_i);

  i2s_driver_install(I2S_OUTPUT_PORT, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
  i2s_set_pin (I2S_OUTPUT_PORT, &pin_config_o);
}

void setup() {

  // Configuración del monitor serial
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(" ");

  i2s_install();
  delay(1000);
  
  i2s_start(I2S_INPUT_PORT);
  i2s_start(I2S_OUTPUT_PORT);
}

void loop() {
    size_t bytesIn = 0;
    esp_err_t result = i2s_read(I2S_INPUT_PORT, &inputSoundBuffer, I2S_BUFFER_LEN, &bytesIn, portMAX_DELAY);

    if (result == ESP_OK)
    {

      if (bytesIn > 0) {
        for (int16_t i = 0; i < bytesIn ; i++){ //samples; ++i) {
          outputSoundBuffer[i] = (inputSoundBuffer[i]);
        }


        size_t  transBytes = bytesIn;
        i2s_write(I2S_OUTPUT_PORT, (char *) outputSoundBuffer, I2S_BUFFER_LEN, &transBytes, portMAX_DELAY);

    
      }
  }

}
```

I'm trying to communicate full duplex via i2s protocol. I expecting to make a real time monitoring of audio input signal.